# findoverlap region with some condition

Tags: r

I try to use findOverlap to solve this problem but I'm only find overlap region with no condition, so If I have some conditon to select data. How should I do?

Let's assume I have two data frame  like below

dataframe a

```
Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length, length/probe, region
CNV1234,  2000,  3000,  CN gain,  23,  235, 9, intron
CNV1534,  1200,  1800,  CN loss,  60,  600  10, exon
```

dataframe b

```
Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length, length/probe, region
CNV234,  2500,  3500,  CN gain,  23,  235, 9, exon 
CNV34,  1200,  1800,  CN loss,  60,  600  10, intron
```

I have two questions

First ,I want to find overlap  between this two dataframe which CNV is have more than 50% length overlap  and this overlap is in intron region

Second,  I want to know the length of overlap region.

I want my result have a dataframe look like this

```
Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length, length/probe, region, overlap, length of overlap
CNV1234,  2000,  3000,  CN gain,  23,  235, 9, intron, CNV234, 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your data

```
a <- read.csv(textConnection(
    "Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length, length/probe, region
     CNV1234,  2000,  3000,  CN gain,  23,  235, 9, intron
     CNV1534,  1200,  1800,  CN loss,  60,  600  10, exon"))

b <- read.csv(textConnection(
    "Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length, length/probe, region
     CNV234,  2500,  3500,  CN gain,  23,  235, 9, exon 
     CNV34,  1200,  1800,  CN loss,  60,  600  10, intron"))
```

Load the [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package (I'm assuming that your data actually come from several chromosomes, and you'd like to do this across all; "A" is a chromosome name)

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr1 <- with(a, GRanges("A", IRanges(start, stop - 1L),
                       Sample=Sample, event=event))
gr2 <- with(b, GRanges("A", IRanges(start, stop - 1L, names=Sample),
                       Region=Sample))
```

Note how GRanges denotes ranges (1-based, including start and end coordinates). Find all overlaps between these objects (you could use min.overlaps to exclude some overlaps, e.g., those that are shorter than 1/2 the minimum width)

```
h <- findOverlaps(gr1, gr2)
```

It's not clear what "50%" of the width is -- width of a? b? -- so I calculate the width of all overlaps, then keep those whose width is greater than 1/2 the width of "a"

```
wd <- width(pintersect(gr1[queryHits(h)], gr2[subjectHits(h)]))
ok <- wd > width(gr1[queryHits(h)]) / 2
h <- h[ok]
```

Finally, I assemble the result by selecting the queries that satisfy the overlap criteria and adding the metadata columns (`mcols`) and width of overlap of the regions they overlap

```
result <- gr1[queryHits(h)]
mcols(result) <- cbind(mcols(result), mcols(gr2[subjectHits(h)]))
result$`width of overlap` <- wd[ok]
```

The result could be coerced back to a data frame with `as.data.frame(result)`, or perhaps your downstream analysis is done naturally with the GRanges infrastructure?

It's better to ask questions about [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/) packages on the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) (no subscription required). There are likely more efficient ways to do this, and the people on that mailing list will provide these solutions.